# Pull result from HTML template google apps script in PHP

Tags: google-apps-script, embed

I have made a small script in Google Apps. Using

```
    function doGet (e) {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Agenda').evaluate();
    }
```

with the template that creates a table with a few for loops. The table shows up fine when using the URL.

This is the result: 
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzllGcNnzy6HkQwiL9TfZJdkNS9hqyEvT4NuoR2FuXwlBfdxGY/exec

(it is public anyway).

I want to take this simple HTML table and use it in a Wordpress-site, and style it externally. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JSONP will probably help you.

Try creating a JSON object like to hold your table conted HTML like `{myTable: "htmlCodeForTheTable"}` and then serving it as JSONP with GAS HtmlService. Doing it like this you will be able to insert the table HTML code in your page DOM using javascript. The table will then be styled according to the site's CSS.

Please find a simple but efficient example by [Cesar Anton](https://plus.google.com/105228553334612207418/posts) at:
https://plus.google.com/105228553334612207418/posts/GefPWdx88F8

Comment: Awesome, that was pretty easy... ! 

In your post I found the Contentservice, which i forgot but is essential.